# Self-referencing Rails HABTM association works one way only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have documents and some of them are related and the *relation is symmetric*. That said, I tried to model this relation according to HABTM instructions for both [association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) and [join table](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_join_table).

I can do `d1.related_documents << d2` for two instances of Document. `d1.related_documents` works and returns related documents, but `d2.related_documents` returns an empty set.

I have declared tables and model as follows:

- documents table

  ```
  create_table :documents do |t|
    t.string :matter
    t.string :url_id, unique: true
    t.text :body

    t.timestamps
  end
  ```
- join table

  ```
  create_join_table :documents, :documents, table_name: :related_documents, id: false do |t|
    t.references :referent, foreign_key: { to_table: :documents, 
                                           primary_key: :url_id }, index: true
    t.references :reference, foreign_key: { to_table: :documents, 
                                            primary_key: :url_id }, index: true
    end
  end
  ```
- the model

  ```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :related_documents, join_table: :related_documents, 
                                              class_name: "Document", 
                                              foreign_key: :referent_id, 
                                              association_foreign_key: :reference_id
  ```

Comment: Did you also call `d2.related_documents` at all prior to `d1.related_documents << d2`, perchance?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I’ve tried it now and it seems to behave identically. What could be the result of calling `d2.related_documents`?

Comment: It could be the association-caching on the other model. You then need to `reload` to make sure it's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self referential habtm is a little outside the standard Rails toolbox. You need to adjust the finder_sql or have 2 relations:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :related_documents, join_table: :related_documents, 
                                            class_name: "Document", 
                                            foreign_key: :referent_id, 
                                            association_foreign_key: :reference_id
has_and_belongs_to_many :referenced_documents, join_table: :related_documents, 
                                            class_name: "Document", 
                                            foreign_key: :reference_id, 
                                            association_foreign_key: :referent_id
```

If you need to unionize the results into one SQL, you need to adjust the Finder-SQL, see e.g. https://gist.github.com/srpouyet/4121517

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :related_documents,
                          class_name: 'Document',
                          join_table: :related_documents,
                          foreign_key: :reference_id,
                          association_foreign_key: :referent_id,
                          uniq: true,
                          finder_sql: proc { 
     %(SELECT DISTINCT "documents".* FROM "documents"
       INNER JOIN "related_documents" 
         ON "documents"."id" = "related_documents"."referent_id"
       WHERE "related_documents"."reference_id" =  #{id}
       UNION
       SELECT DISTINCT "documents".* FROM "documents"
       INNER JOIN "related_documents" 
         ON "documents"."id" = "related_documents"."reference_id"
       WHERE "related_documents"."referent_id" =  #{id} 
       )}
```

Comment: This indeed works! Though `finder_sql` [has been removed from Rails since 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40594111/2948889). I took the liberty to add `scope` based alternative to your answer.